# finding an expression from a truth table

Tags: logic, truthtable

I have a truth table like this:

a     b      sel     O

F     F       F      F

F     F       T      F

F     T       F      F

F     T       T      T

T     F       F      T

T     F       T      F

T     T       F      T

T     T       T      T

so O is the output column, sel is basically a selector. So when sel = F, the O will be the value of a, and if sel= T, the O will be the value of b.

So I was able to come up with an expression (without regarding b input) that correctly matches the output of sel and a, when sel = F:
a $$\lor$$ sel  (for example you could check that this expression $$a v sel$$ would produce correctly all the combination of values of a, sel and O, without regarding the value of b)

And similarly for matching output of sel and b, when sel = T:
$$b ^ sel$$ (for example you could check that this expression $$b ^ sel$$ would produce correctly all the combination of values of b, sel and O, without regarding the value of a)

But now I am not sure how to come up with an expression that would correctly put together $$a v sel$$ and $$b ^ sel$$ to have a final expression that matches the truth table above.

Answer (score 0):

```
(!s && a) || (s && b)
```

If `s` is false, the left side takes the value of `a`, and the right side is false (and thus ignored).

If `s` is true, the right side takes the value of `b`, and the left side is false (and thus ignored).

Comment: HI, sorry for my stupidity, may I know what is &&? and || here? could you use the "or" "and" "xor" notation in your answer instead? sorry because I think you are using regular expression here.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm using the usual computer programming operators, `&&` is "and", `||` is "or", `!` is "not". It is easier to type than the corresponding mathematical symbols. (Also, notably, Stack Overflow does not parse LaTeX, so `$$\lor$$` is really hard to read.) I have not used "xor" (nor regular expressions).